# How do I initialize array when I do not know how much items will be there

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I have a task, where I need to store data into arrays. But the problem which I met, that for using array I should initialize it. But I do not know how much items will be stored there.
For example:

```
int[] array_name;
array_name = {1,2,3};
```

But my task is find numbers from string, and stored them into array, how much numbers will be there I do not know. Is there any universal way to initialize array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case you use an `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList` uses internally an array which grows automatically.
If you insist on using an array, you can create one, once you have read in all data into your `ArrayList`.

Example:

```
List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a List for that:

```
List<Integer> lIntegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

For using that there is no need to know how much Integers you have.

Answer (score 1):

Create a List...

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

or with generics

```
List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
```

If you definetly need an array, then after adding everything to the list, make it an array.
More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Ok, thnx I will try it)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are not dynamic. You can use list instead.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Due to autoboxing feature you can freely add either Integer objects or primitive ints to this list.